# Activating a virtual env not working

Tags: python, virtualenv

I created two virtualenv and I installed two different versions of django. Now I have a problem to activate the two environment, I do like this :

```
source Django1.6/bin/activate
```

Then I see that the environment was activated. Then I do :

```
pip install django # for test
```

and I get this message :

```
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): 
                                 django in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
```

This tell that the environment was not activated but it use the default one. Why I'm getting this?

Comment: The message mentions `/usr/local/lib/python2.7` so it might be the case that you have Django installed system-wide. Could you check this?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

When changing the environment location we must execute `virtualenv` on the new folder.
When looking to activate file I have found this code :

```
VIRTUAL_ENV="/old/folder"
export VIRTUAL_ENV
```

This variable will updated when we execute `virtualenv` on the new folder.

Answer (score 20):

Lets say you have got two virtual environments installed **venv1** and **venv2**.

```
virtualenv venv1
virtualenv venv2
```

Virtualenv will create the directories and install the relevant Python libraries, PIP, etc.

Activate each environment one at a time.do your stuff and deactivate.

```
source venv1/bin/activate    
# make changes to the environment. i.e pip install django==1.6.8
deactivate

source venv2/bin/activate   
# make changes to the environment. i.e pip install django==1.7.1
deactivate
```

can check installed django versions.

```
source venv1/bin/activate
python
import django
django.VERSION
[. . . . make note of the version of django running . . . .]
deactivate

source venv2/bin/activate
python
import django
django.VERSION
[. . . . make note of the version of django running . . . .]
deactivate
```

If everything was done correctly you should see a different version of Django running in each virtualenv.

Comment: Upvote for the `deactivate` command, I've been looking all over for that. @SiyaramMalav

Answer (score 0):

In My Case the Problem was that i was not using source while activating virtual environment

Mistake i was making

```
venv\Script\activate
```

The Correct Way

```
source venv\Script\activate
```

Answer (score 0):

If you renamed any directories that contain your project then you will have to recreate the virtual environment because your PATH variable does not get updated automatically.

```
python -m venv venv --clear
source venv/bin/activate
```