# Python - Virtual Environment uses System Directories

Tags: python, virtualenv

I've created a Python virtual environment, and activate it by doing:

```
joe@joe-mint $ source ./venvs/deep-learning/bin/activate
```

Which turns the prompt into:

```
(deep-learning) joe@joe-mint $
```

Now whenever I run a python package or try to install one, the system seems to ignore the fact that it's in a virtual environment and does things system-wide:

```
(deep-learning) joe@joe-mint $ which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

The same happens when I try to install new packages that aren't on my system; it installs them to the system files (i.e. /usr/bin) instead of the virtual environment.

What's wrong with my virtual environment? How do I get it to ignore system files and do everything inside the environment?

---

I've looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21240653/how-to-install-a-package-inside-virtualenv) question which says to use an explicit flag when creating the virtual environment to make it use the local environment packages, but I used `python-3.5 -m venv` to create the virtual environment, and this flag is removed in this version as it's now a default option.

I've also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24011399/activating-a-virtual-env-not-working) question and can confirm that the `VIRTUAL_ENV` variable is set correctly in the `activate` file of the virtual environment.

Comment: What's the result of `echo $PATH` ? activate is supposed to place the venv's binaries at the front of PATH

Comment: @jonatan - Turns out that because I installed the venv without pip, the `pip` command was using the system's one. Apparently this causes it to install packages to the system despite being in the virtual environment. I don't really understand it, but I managed to solve it in my answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [virtualenv does not include pip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34503686/virtualenv-does-not-include-pip)

Comment: @holdenweb - I deliberately installed the venv without pip because of [a bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/488529/pyvenv-3-4-error-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1) that prevented me from doing otherwise.

Comment: And that's what's wrong with your virtual environment

Comment: @holdenweb - I was expecting the system's `pip` to install things into the venv since it had been activated.

Comment: As you've discovered that doesn't work because virtualenvs rely on `$PATH` modifications to pick up the environment. Since you are using 3.4 (the bug is fixed in 3.5 and later) you might instead want to consider installing `virtualenv` into your system Pyrthon (assuming root permissions) and the nusing that rather than `pyvenv`.

Comment: @holdenweb - I'm using 3.5, not 3.4. Also, I didn't actually use `pyvenv`. I used `python-3.5 -m venv` as described in my question.

Comment: @holdenweb -  I might be wrong in assuming it's the same bug! Sorry if that's the case. I'm not sure why I ran into the error; that linked bug is just my best guess.

Comment: In your answer you say you created the virtualenv without `pip` due to a long-standing bug, but that bug doesn't apply to 3.5, doe sit?

Comment: @holdenweb - Alright, I'm not sure what caused the error, but installing without `pip` as directed on that question solved the problem. Initially I ran `python3.5 -m venv ./deep-learning` which gave the error: `Error: Command '['...../deep-learning/bin/python3.5', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1`, just like the linked bug. Installing without `pip` using the `--without-pip` flag worked.

Answer (score 1):

Here was the problem:

It seems that if you run `pip` on a venv without a local `pip` installation, then it will default to the system's `pip` outside the venv. Even if you've activated a virtual environment, this seems to want to install packages on the system rather than in the venv.

Here was the solution:

- First, I had to install the virtual environment without pip due to [a bug that has long remained unresolved](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488529/pyvenv-3-4-error-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1).
- Second, I installed `pip` in the virtual environment as per the instruction [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34214621/1351182). However, doing so required using some temporary folders that for some reason my user didn't have access to. So this failed, and the only way I could get it to work was to become root.

  1. `sudo su`
  2. `activate ..../venvs/deep-learning/bin/activate` to activate the virtual environment.
  3. `curl --silent --show-error --retry 5 https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python` as per the answer linked above.

  Although `which pip` now indicated the correct `pip` (inside the venv) was being used, running `pip` would use the system one! Deactivating (`deactivate`) and reactivating the venv solved this.

  Now it took me a while to realise that having installed this as root caused me permission errors when trying to install more packages using `pip` inside the virtual environment.
- `chown <user>:<group> -R ..../venvs/deep-learning/*`

And that was it. After these steps, I could activate the venv and run `pip` correctly. It would use the `pip` inside the venv, and install packages inside the `venv`.

Comment: This worked for me, but I also had to remove the system python paths from my $PYTHONPATH and replace it with the venvs path: 

$export PYTHONPATH=..../venvs/deep-learning/lib/python3.8/site-packages